# Replacing structure member name by variable

Tags: c++, struct

Is there any way to replace `schema.liczby` and `schema.studenci` by something like `schema.($variable)`? It would be nice to avoid duplicate of code doing the same thing in this case only for different structures.

```
string getFieldType(string field_name, SCHEMA schema, string table)
{
    if (table == "liczby")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < schema.liczby.integers.size(); i++)
        {
            if (schema.liczby.integers[i] == field_name)
            {
                return "int";
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < schema.liczby.strings.size(); i++)
        {
            if (schema.liczby.strings[i] == field_name)
            {
                return "string";
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < schema.liczby.doubles.size(); i++)
        {
            if (schema.liczby.doubles[i] == field_name)
            {
                return "double";
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < schema.liczby.booleans.size(); i++)
        {
            if (schema.liczby.booleans[i] == field_name)
            {
                return "double";
            }
        }
    }
    else if (table == "studenci")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < schema.studenci.integers.size(); i++)
        {
            if (schema.studenci.integers[i] == field_name)
            {
                return "int";
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < schema.studenci.strings.size(); i++)
        {
            if (schema.studenci.strings[i] == field_name)
            {
                return "string";
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < schema.studenci.doubles.size(); i++)
        {
            if (schema.studenci.doubles[i] == field_name)
            {
                return "double";
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < schema.studenci.booleans.size(); i++)
        {
            if (schema.studenci.booleans[i] == field_name)
            {
                return "double";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot do what you're looking for in languages (such as C++) that do not provide reflection.

Comment: There might be a way to do what you want, but not in the way you suggest. Could you show us the definition of `SCHEMA`?

Comment: This smells a bit like [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  C++ has plenty of type-wise functionality, but not through reflection like this.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LkvQwtzn

Answer (score 1):

We can refactor your code a lot.  There are a lot of ways to skin this cat.  I think a `std::map` makes things pretty straight forward, but YMMV.  I think you should change the type of the second map, so you can store type + value (`boost:variant` or polymorphic setup might would probably work well.)  This code is just a starting point.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> SCHEMA;

int main() {
    SCHEMA schema;

    // Schema table
    schema["liczby"]["wartosc"] = "column";
    schema["liczby"]["wartość"] = "int";
    schema["studenci"]["indeks"] = "column";
    schema["studenci"]["imie"] = "column";
    schema["studenci"]["nazwisko"] = "column";
    schema["przedmioty"]["id"] = "column";
    schema["przedmioty"]["nazwa"] = "column";
    schema["przedmioty"]["semestr"] = "column";
    schema["sale"]["nazwa"] = "column";
    schema["sale"]["rozmiar"] = "column";
    schema["sale"]["projektor"] = "column";
    schema["sale"]["powierzchnia"] = "column";
}

std::string getFieldType(std::string field_name, SCHEMA& schema, std::string table) {
    return schema[table][field_name];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No problem. Your `LICZBY_SCHEMA`, `STUDENCI_SCHEMA`, `PRZEDMIOTY_SCHEMA` and `SALE_SCHEMA` are identical, so we replace them all with `BASIC_SCHEMA`. Then the code becomes much simpler:

```
struct BASIC_SCHEMA
{
  vector<string> columns;
  vector<string> integers;
  vector<string> strings;
  vector<string> booleans;
  vector<string> doubles;
};

struct SCHEMA
{
  BASIC_SCHEMA liczby;
  BASIC_SCHEMA studenci;
  BASIC_SCHEMA przedmioty;
  BASIC_SCHEMA sale;
};

string getFieldType(string field_name, SCHEMA schema, string table)
{
  BASIC_SCHEMA subSchema;

  if (table == "liczby")
    subSchema = schema.liczby;
  else if (table == "studenci")
    subSchema = schema.studenci;
  else
    return("");

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < subSchema.integers.size(); i++)
    {
      if (subSchema.integers[i] == field_name)
        {
          return "int";
        }
    }
  ...
 }
```

We can make it even more concise with e.g. `find(...)`, but that's another story.